# How to get comments and string in regex?

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code, syntax, syntax-highlighting

i have create a programming language [KAGSA](https://github.com/kagsa/kagsa), and i have to create a syntax highlighter i start with VSCode highlighter i write every thing well but i have problem with regex of strings (more than one line) and comments (more than one line) this is the code :
Match is the code:
Comments :

```json
"comments": {
            "patterns": [{
                "name": "comment.line.shebang.kagsa",
                "match": "//..*|/\\*(.*?|\n)*\\*/|//|/\\**\\*"
            }]
        },
```

The problem is wit the `/*Comment*/` comment.
and string code :

```json
"strings": {
            "name": "string.quoted.double.kagsa",
            "patterns": [{
                "name": "string.quoted.double.kagsa",
                "match": "'(.*?)'|\"(.*?)\"|``(.*?|\n)*``"
            }]
        },
```

my problem is with ``` ``String`` ```
and the Color i get :

[the output color][https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPbS0.png]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have this issue because `match` doesn't work for multiline string literals.
I found a similar [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51557913/13813542).
As said by Gama11 in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51559355/13813542):

> Try to use a `begin` / `end` pattern instead of a simple `match`.